# Is it possible to add Instabug / Crashlytics to Qt Android application?

Tags: firebase, qt, crashlytics, qtandroidextras, instabug

I would like to understand if we can integrate Instabug or Crashlytics to an Android application developed using Qt 5.9.1. Also, will these tools be able to catch and report exceptions thrown in the C++ layer ?